# jquery draggable under mask, for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/QdbNe/1/

You can check that sample of what I tried. Basically, I need to be able to drag around the three colored squares within the semi-transparent mask depending on which one the user clicks. But the problem is how do I determine which child the user is clicking on? because, the click event actually occurs on the mask, instead of the children.

So I need to do something like

```
$("#mask").mousedown(function(e){
        var currentChild = //Somehow fetch the current child
        currentChild.trigger(e);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for the transparent mask? If not, the following could work:

```
$("#child1, #child2, #child3").draggable({
    stop:function(e,ui){
        alert(e.target.id);
    }
});
```

Updated Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QdbNe/1/

Comment: no, I need the mask div cause in practice it is supposed to have a image....this is just a sample of the structure. And logically your solution wouldn't work, cause I need the child identifier before the drag starts....not when it stops

Comment: If you have to have the transparent image on top then on mask click you would get the square with matching coordinates (use jquery .position).  Then use the mask mousemove() event to move the matching square.  FYI, if you need the id on drag start use the start event of draggable, see updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QdbNe/1/

Comment: Jonathan thanks for trying, but:
1) I can't simply use offset, can I? cause I have to find if the mouse coordinate is within a div's bounds, and that requires considerable resources for calculation especially considering javascript's speed, and the fact there can be quite a huge number of child elements

2) I don't know if you noticed, but simply "run"-ing code on jsfiddle doesn't update it. You need to hit the "Update" button after you are certain of your changes. This will give you a new link for the updated version of the code.

Comment: You can use .position in lieu of .offset.  With a lot of elements it will be intensive to calculate their initial bounds and then to sync their position on mousemove.  Thanks on the jsfiddle comment, if needed http://jsfiddle.net/QdbNe/4/

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer of Jonathan solve the issue with

```
$("#mask").mousedown(function(e){
        $("#child1").trigger(e);
    });
```

So my element is visually partially hidden but I can move it.

Comment: You are missing the point of the question..."multiple draggable elements under one single mask". Let's say you have `#child1`,`#child2`,`#child3`, under `#mask`, then if you simply trigger mousedown on all of them at once, all of them will get dragged together, even if the user is hovering on only one of them.